# How to use specific trait out of many possible ones?

Tags: generics, rust

I have some structs that can implement traits, and an enum representing which trait to use.

If I store the struct in a variable, match on the enum, and then run the trait fn everything is OK.

If I try and take out that match and place it into a re-usable function, the generic T is too general.

What is the correct type signature for taking this match and placing it into a re-usable function?

The code is simplified, in my code base I have a larger process function that manages perhaps 20 different struct types, but they all will implement the same T{X} level, and must switch on the enum to process each one - I do not want to have to write that match branch many times.

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3dbcf3c2fec54aa9f347aa1609796a4f)

```rust
struct SA {
    sa: String
}

struct SB {
    sb: String
}

trait T1 {
    fn get_static_data() -> &'static str;
}

trait T2: T1 {
    fn get_ins_data(&self) -> String;    
}

trait T3 {
    fn get_static_data_slightly_diff() -> &'static str;
}

trait T4 : T3 {
    fn get_ins_data(&self) -> String;
}

impl T1 for SA {
    fn get_static_data() -> &'static str {
        "static"
    }
}
impl T2 for SA {
     fn get_ins_data(&self) -> String {
        self.sa.clone() + Self::get_static_data()
    }
}
impl T3 for SA {
    fn get_static_data_slightly_diff() -> &'static str {
        "static, a bit diff from T1"
    }
}
impl T4 for SA {
    fn get_ins_data(&self) -> String {
        self.sa.clone() + Self::get_static_data_slightly_diff()
    }
}

enum WhichToUse {
    T2,
    T4
}

fn process_error<T>(wtu: &WhichToUse, s: &T) -> bool {    
    // Not Ok: T is too general.
    match wtu {
        WhichToUse::T2 => {
            T2::get_ins_data(&s);
            return true;
        },
        WhichToUse::T4 => {
            T4::get_ins_data(&s);
            return true;
        }
    }
}

fn process_ok(wtu: &WhichToUse) {
    let s = SA {sa: "sa".to_string()};
    
    // Ok: the compiler checks variable `s` has the correct trait
    match wtu {
        WhichToUse::T2 => {
            T2::get_ins_data(&s);
        },
        WhichToUse::T4 => {
            T4::get_ins_data(&s);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let wtu = WhichToUse::T2;
    let sa = SA {sa: "sa".to_string()};
    
    process_error(&wtu, &sa);   
}
```

Comment: What you want is not possible. Rust is a strongly typed language. Maybe you could implement a common trait for `get_static_data ` and `get_ins_data`, and work with that?

Comment: I did think of that, both implementations are semantically the same in meaning, but will have different type signatures and lifetimes. I think I need a unifying trait that hides the implementation details - Im investigating a generic enum to represent the "this trait OR that trait" (instead of the default `where T: this + that`)